# Installing Ubuntu gnome 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I downloaded ISO file but when I try to boot from USB it says `bootmgr is missing`. I can boot that ISO file in virtual machine so I assume the file is OK. I had Ubuntu 14.04 with unity installed but didn't like unity at all.

I burned ISO file to DVD but can't boot from that either, should I download the file again? I have a very low speed connection.

Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Into terminal type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

Then:

`sudo apt-get update && ssudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

When these have finished, log out of ubuntu, click on the circle with the ubuntu logo near the password box, and choose one of the gnome options (you probably want just Gnome). It will always be the last chosen one by default (so after a restart, you can just log straight in).

Comment: I'm using windows 8 now, I can boot the other Ubuntu (with unity) without any problem but I read that shouldn't install gnome shell over unity so I downloaded the Ubuntu gnome 14.04 from here http://ubuntugnome.org/download/ but I ca't boot and install.

Comment: There is no 'installing over', my method is installing alongside, all inside one boot. There is no need to have 2 ubuntu's, one with gnome and one with unity on the same machine, especially as you can't use all the disk space, you'd have to partition. Because of that, I'd suggest that you install it in the same OS.

Comment: sorry but I couldn't say what I meant! I don't wanna install 2 OS. I had Ubuntu 14.04 with unity desktop the last two weeks, then I decided to install Ubuntu with gnome desktop. I didn't have any problem, both Ubuntu and windows were OK and worked alongside correctly. but now when i try to install this one USB or DVD won't boot! I thought it was something wrong with my laptop but it wasn't, so it must be the file I downloaded.

Comment: @user292314 - This doesn't install a new OS, it installs a new desktop - it should have no effect on the existing Unity desktop. You can then pick which desktop to use at the login screen. You don't need a different install of Ubuntu for a different desktop. In Ubuntu and other Linux systems,there are [many Desktops available](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available).

Answer (score 0):

`bootmgr is missing` - Seems you are not booting from the pen drive or DVD.

You can boot from either of these by selecting them in the boot selection menu from the BIOS.

Comment: I select USB in Bios and it gives this error. when I try to boot from DVD it directly logs into windows like there is no file on it! tried with another laptop but I got the same error.

Comment: How did you write it to the pen drive or dvd ? extracted the ISO contents and pasted them eh ?

Comment: nope! i burned 3 DVDs using UltaISO, Nero and the windows itself. but all the same. problem is that I can boot DVD in virtual machine and even work with Ubuntu in virtual environment. because of that I doubt if the file is corrupted. it's driving me crazy!!

Comment: There are lots of instructions on how to do this, both [for DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) and [for USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Use `Linux Live Creator` or `Universal Usb installer` from Windows for creating a bootable pen drive